# How can i attach a file Like Readme.md In python setup.py while making a module

Tags: python

I am trying to upgrade a module named computerspeak and i want to attach a Readme.md to my module but i am not able to attach it 
 I tried Using

```
Long_Description: file: 'Readme.md',
```

But I Didn't Work I Just Showed

```
Readme.md
```

In the Long description area

Comment: The directive you tried to use is not valid, though it coincidentally happens to be valid Python syntax (you are declaring that the string `'README.md'` should be of type `file` with a type annotation). It's not clear why you expected this to work or where you picked it up; probably it's acceptable in some other file with a different format, but then you should use that file and format and the associated build tools instead of `setup.py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This Should work

```py
from setuptools import setup

# read the contents of your README file
from pathlib import Path
this_directory = Path(__file__).parent
long_description = (this_directory / "README.md").read_text()

setup(
    name='an_example_package',
    # other arguments omitted
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown'
)
```

***source: https://packaging.python.org/guides/making-a-pypi-friendly-readme/***

Comment: it's not work dude.